# Is it possible to make scrollable div without width inside column stay of the same width as column when adding new elements iside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simplified structure:
[image]

what I want is that brown div would stay fixed with the width of the column when I add green divs inside of it inspite of their length. So it should stretch and shrink along with table and column when I resize page but stay fixed when long content is added inside of it with scrollers added. But it doesn't work: instead of adding scrollers to the brown div all browsers stretch the div and its parent table to fit the newly added element thus violating width properties for the table and column. Here's a sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fu() {
    var d=document.createElement('div');
    d.style.backgroundColor='limegreen';
    d.style.whiteSpace='nowrap';
    var t = document.createTextNode("a;sdlkf asdof aposidfj pasij fpajfpad fpasd p a ds asdjfp jspfia sdpiajds fapdfklgpreogin vnzv.,zxvpvrepi dfvndpf nzd;bnz[obnrb oino");
    d.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("dqd").appendChild(d);  
}
</script>
<table style="width:70%">
    <tr>
        <td style="align:right">Title:</td>
        <td style="width:90%">
            <div style="height:300px;overflow:auto;background-color:brown" id="dqd">
                <div style="background-color: limegreen; white-space: nowrap">
                    LoL
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="fu()">OK</button>
```

Comment: Your question title is so messy... can you clarify ? MAke it SIMPLE. You will get an answer quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `d.style.whiteSpace='nowrap';` as that is what is causing your issue. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space for documentation on the line wrapping.

If you really need to keep the `nowrap` then I would suggest change from a table layout to using `div` elements for the layout. One possible solution is http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid which I would recommend.

```js
function fu() {
    var d=document.createElement('div');
    d.style.backgroundColor='limegreen';
    d.style.whiteSpace='nowrap';
    
    var t = document.createTextNode("a;sdlkf asdof aposidfj pasij fpajfpad fpasd p a ds asdjfp jspfia sdpiajds fapdfklgpreogin vnzv.,zxvpvrepi dfvndpf nzd;bnz[obnrb oino");
    d.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("dqd").appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:70%">
  <div style="display: inline-block; align:right; width: 10%;">Title:</div>
  <div style="width:90%; display: inline-block;">
            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
            <div style="max-width:100%;height:300px;overflow:auto;background-color:brown" id="dqd">
                <div style="background-color: limegreen; white-space: nowrap">
                    LoL
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
        </div>
</div>
<button onclick="fu()">OK</button>
```

Comment: But I want each entry to take one line only

Comment: @mykola Added info for that case. I believe you will have to change from `div` elements in a `table` to `div` inside `div`. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for a nice framework for it.

Comment: Well, with `float:left` for the title `div` it seems like it's working though it has some issue with divs overlapping when shrinking the page, but it's not that serious. So, thanks! I'll try to redesign my page to use divs instead of table.